# Why my js function need somethitg from my php iterator?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, foreach, getelementbyid

I have two foreach iterations on different pages. One of them is on the home page. I also have a js script that interacts with the elements of both iterators via ID.

What can I do to stop interacting with the iterator on the homepage? I have already removed the ID from him. I am now also getting this error on the homepage

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getAttribute' of null at window.onload

Php/html iterator:

```
<? foreach($catalog_product as $key => $catalog_product_value): ?>
  <div class="card">
    .....
    <div class="card__side card__side--back card__side--back-1">
      <h3><?=$catalog_product_value['header']?></h3>
      <p class="flip-text"><?=$catalog_product_value['title']?></p>
      <?=$catalog_product_value['content']?>
      <div 
        data-item="product" 
        data-item_id="<?=$catalog_product_value['product_id']?>" 
        data-id="card_<?=($key + 1)?>" 
        data-title="<?=htmlspecialchars($catalog_product_value['header'])?>"
        <? if (!empty($catalog_product_value['options'])): ?>
          data-options="<?=htmlspecialchars(json_encode($catalog_product_value['options']), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')?>"
        <? else: ?> 
          data-price="<?=preg_replace('/[^0-9.]+/', '', $catalog_product_value['price'])?>"
        <? endif; ?>
        class="buy_product_form pop_maker">
          <?=$catalog_product_value['price']?>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<? endforeach;?>
```

js code:

```
window.onload = function(){
  button = document.getElementById('buy_product_form');
  var atr = button.getAttribute('data-title');
      var id = button.getAttribute('data-id');
      var options = button.getAttribute('data-options');
      var price = button.getAttribute('data-price');
      var item_id = button.getAttribute('data-item_id');
      var item = button.getAttribute('data-item');
      button.id = id;

      var _form = document.createElement('form');
      .....
};
```

Comment: You've removed the id, hence the DOM method can't find an element by the id.

Comment: @Teemu I need to move id back?

Comment: Probably not, you've to rethink the logic, ids should be unique within the document. What you need is to base your DOM query to class instead of id.

Comment: getElementById finds ids, not classes